# mailing thru ssh

Tags: email, imap, mail-transport-agent

<sup>(I am a Linux only user & [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) software developer, and use Linux since kernel 0.99.15 e.g. the previous century)</sup>

I have a VPS host `ovh.starynkevitch.net`  (running Linux) which is also the *MX* host for my email. It is getting emails only for less than a dozen users (my relatives, i.e. kids, grand-children, wife). So a quite small traffic. the MTA is `exim4` ...

<sup>I specifically don't want to use *gmail*</sup>

I have secure `ssh` (public-key, so without passwords) access to that machine (from every -latop or desktop machine I am working on).

I want to be able to read (and post, but SMTP forwarding is not an issue) my email thru it.
Up to now, I forwarded my email (to some home server). In practice, I want to run some graphical MUA (e.g. `sylpheed` or `evolution` ...) because I am tired of `mutt`...

I also want to be able to use some spam filter like [spamoracle](http://spamoracle.forge.ocamlcore.org/); it has to run on my VPS host (not locally on the MUA machines). And I need to conveniently be able (with a single keystroke!) to improve (by the usual machine learning techniques) its filtering.

I was thinking of installing some IMAP server (like the `imapd` from GNU mailutils). But then, it is less easy to use *spamoracle* with it.

I thought of:

1. Using `imapd` above SSL or some other secure transport. But then I am not familiar with the configuration, and I have no idea if the SSL should be related to my `ssh` settings or not.
2. doing port redirection with `ssh`

Any hints or some other solutions?

Comment: What about a web MUA like roundcube serving IMAP mail boxes (and all webmails have plugins for spam filtering or integration with spam filtering frameworks)?

Comment: If all you want is tunnel through `ssh`, you can use `-D` and configure your MUA to use a SOCKS proxy.